# Android error: annotation value not of an allowable type

Tags: android, notifications

I am following a tutorial to generate a notification, but I am getting an error an `annotation value not of an allowable type`. I have seen the answer to similar questions but unable to solve mine. So, any Help?

```
public interface APIServices {

@Header(
        value = { // error is on this lin
                "Authorization: key=AAAAaTlmErw:APA91bH8nQxh3Hxn-SIA9u0nzlAIn96Ks1prH950uXVOUKQiDj8Bxdt2mR98qE7xqQaxbbKVcxwgromyYGwbw4xRYJ_47hu5_jmyQ5Yun1_KgTokpAEPNDIekGzldTAKp4IVnKvU8HVk",
                "Content-Type: application/json"
        }
)

@POST("fcm/send")
Call<MyResponse> sendNotification(@Body Sender body);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replace

```
@Header(
        value = { // error is on this lin
                "Authorization: key=AAAAaTlmErw:APA91bH8nQxh3Hxn-SIA9u0nzlAIn96Ks1prH950uXVOUKQiDj8Bxdt2mR98qE7xqQaxbbKVcxwgromyYGwbw4xRYJ_47hu5_jmyQ5Yun1_KgTokpAEPNDIekGzldTAKp4IVnKvU8HVk",
                "Content-Type: application/json"
        }
)
```

to

```
@Headers({ 
                "Authorization: key=AAAAaTlmErw:APA91bH8nQxh3Hxn-SIA9u0nzlAIn96Ks1prH950uXVOUKQiDj8Bxdt2mR98qE7xqQaxbbKVcxwgromyYGwbw4xRYJ_47hu5_jmyQ5Yun1_KgTokpAEPNDIekGzldTAKp4IVnKvU8HVk",
                "Content-Type: application/json"
        }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting with checking your imports at the top of the file and making sure you're importing the @Header and @POST annotations from where you intended.